Given a finitely generated metablian group $G$ with exponential growth, does the ratio of sizes of consecutive balls have a limit?
Suppose $G$ is a metabelian (hence solvable and amenable) group with exponential growth that is finitely generated by a symmetric set S.
Given $k \geq 0$, let $B_k$ be the ball centred at the identity element of $G$ and radius $k$ on the Cayley graph of $G$.
Do we know that if $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} |B_{n+1}|/|B_{n}|$ exists?
Where I got this question from: I think for groups with polynomial growth, we have $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} |B_{n+1}|/|B_{n}|=1$ (https://mathoverflow.net/a/311373/479955). Also, there are examples of group when $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} |B_{n+1}|/|B_{n}|$ doesn't exist (https://mathoverflow.net/a/36132/479955). I am interested if the limit exists for metablian group (or even finitely Abelian-by-$\mathbb Z$ group, e.g. lamplighter group and $BS(1,k)$ groups).
Thank you for reading this, any reference or insight would be really appreciated.

This question would be suitable for MathOverflow, where it would be read by more relevant people. (If so, mention there that it was posted here.)
